# File backup from Android

Tags: android

I am making an app for android that is designed to back up files on the user's phone to a server. How would I do this?

Comment: http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/upload-file-to-remote-server-in-android.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended as a technical forum for questions you have tried to answer yourself, not a please point me to the right source place. However [the Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com) is a good source.

Comment: Start by considering what the server requires of something which wishes to interact with it...